How to show difference between two list of dictionaries
I have these two lists:
list1 = [
    {'name': 'one', 'email': 'one@gmail.com', 'phone': '111'},
    {'name': 'two', 'email': 'two@gmail.com', 'phone': '111'},
    {'name': 'three', 'email': 'three@gmail.com', 'phone': '333'},
    {'name': 'four', 'email': 'four@gmail.com', 'phone': '444'},
]
list2 = [
    {'first_name': 'three', 'email': 'three@gmail.com', 'phone_number': '333'},
    {'first_name': 'four', 'email': 'four@gmail.com', 'phone_number': '444'},
    {'first_name': 'five', 'email': 'five@gmail.com', 'phone_number': '555'},
]

I know how to find difference between two lists based on a key:
list1_only = list(set([x['phone'] for x in list1]) - set([x['phone_number'] for x in list2]))

But the current output is:
['111']

But I'm going to have this output finally:
[
    {'name': 'one', 'email': 'one@gmail.com', 'phone': '111'},
    {'name': 'two', 'email': 'two@gmail.com', 'phone': '111'}
]

I know this way, but I think (and am sure) there's a better way for it:
for l in list1:
    for d in diff:
        if d == l['phone']:
            print(l)


I read other questions like this, but it prints the whole list (not the difference values):
[x for x in list2 if x['phone_number'] not in list1]

Would you please help me regarding this?
Are there any one-line ways to replace with list1_only = list(set([x['phone'] for x in list1]) - set([x['phone_number'] for x in list2]))?

Two questions: (1) Are you only interested in missing phone numbers or do you want to check and compare the complete combination (name, email, phone number)? (2) You are only interested in entries from list1 missing in list2, but not entries from list2 missing in list1, is that correct?

To fix the specific code you've added to the question:
>>> diff = {x['phone'] for x in list1} - {x['phone_number'] for x in list2}
>>> [l for l in list1 if l['phone'] in diff]
[
    {'name': 'one', 'email': 'one@gmail.com', 'phone': '111'},
    {'name': 'two', 'email': 'two@gmail.com', 'phone': '111'}
]

The solution above is a lot more readable than this, but this is an example of how you'd do the same thing in 1 line.
>>> [l for l in list1 if l['phone'] not in {x['phone_number'] for x in list2}]

Bear in mind it will only find items in list1 that are not in list2, and not the other way around, which based on your example it sounds like that's what you're after.

The problem that I see is that the keys in list2 are different from the ones in list1 (name vs. first_name, phone vs. phone_number), so I would map them for comparison:
list1 = [
    {'name': 'one', 'email': 'one@gmail.com', 'phone': '111'},
    {'name': 'two', 'email': 'two@gmail.com', 'phone': '111'},
    {'name': 'three', 'email': 'three@gmail.com', 'phone': '333'},
    {'name': 'four', 'email': 'four@gmail.com', 'phone': '444'},
]
list2 = [
    {'first_name': 'three', 'email': 'three@gmail.com', 'phone_number': '333'},
    {'first_name': 'four', 'email': 'four@gmail.com', 'phone_number': '444'},
    {'first_name': 'five', 'email': 'five@gmail.com', 'phone_number': '555'},
]


mapped = lambda d: {'first_name': d['name'], 'email': d['email'],
                    'phone_number': d['phone']}

diff = [dct for dct in list1 if mapped(dct) not in list2]
print(diff)
# >>> [{'name': 'one', 'email': 'one@gmail.com', 'phone': '111'},
#      {'name': 'two', 'email': 'two@gmail.com', 'phone': '111'}]

Note that I worked with the following assumptions:

I assume you are only interested in entries that are in list1 and missing in list2, but not vice versa (as is implied by the example in your question).
I assume that you want to compare the complete list entries (name, email, phone), as is implied from the expected output that you mention in your question, rather than the phone numbers only, as is implied from the code that you share at the end of your question. In the latter case, Peter's answer has you covered.

In general, it would probably make more sense to unify the key names in the two lists to avoid both a potential source of error and unnecessary conversions. Without knowing your actual underlying use case, I don't know if that's possible or feasible, of course.

Digging inside lists of dictionaries while perfectly doable gets complicated fairly quickly imho. One can gain simplicity and speed switching to data frames.
import polars as pl

list_A = [
    {'name': 'one', 'email': 'one@gmail.com', 'phone': '111'},
    {'name': 'two', 'email': 'two@gmail.com', 'phone': '111'},
    {'name': 'three', 'email': 'three@gmail.com', 'phone': '333'},
    {'name': 'four', 'email': 'four@gmail.com', 'phone': '444'},
]
list_B = [
    {'first_name': 'three', 'email': 'three@gmail.com', 'phone_number': '333'},
    {'first_name': 'four', 'email': 'four@gmail.com', 'phone_number': '444'},
    {'first_name': 'five', 'email': 'five@gmail.com', 'phone_number': '555'},
]

df_a = pl.DataFrame(list_A)
df_b = pl.DataFrame(list_B) #.rename({"first_name": "name", "phone_number": "phone"})

df_a.join(df_b, on="email", how="anti")


which gives:
shape: (2, 3)



name
email
phone




str
str
str


"one"
"one@gmail.com"
"111"


"two"
"two@gmail.com"
"111"



One can also rename columns (assuming the same content type as in the example) to perform more complex joins, stack the dataframes, group_by etc. See the .rename part after the comment.
EDIT: rename columns
